# How can I upload a file to Synology NAS using python with Synology NAS API?

Tags: python, python-requests, synology, nas

I am trying to create a python script to upload an xlsx file to synology NAS using the official Synology NAS API and the python requests module. I have been able to successfully log in and display filestation information using the SYNO.API.Auth and SYNO.FileStation.List apis respectively, but for some reason I can not get the SYNO.FileStation.Upload api to work. Here is my current attempt:

```
file_path = 'path to xlsx file'

# API endpoint for file upload
upload_url = f'{url}/webapi/entry.cgi'

# The file to be uploaded
files = {'file': (open(file_path, 'rb'))}

# Parameters for the file upload request
upload_params = {
    'api': 'SYNO.FileStation.Upload',
    'version': '2',
    'method': 'upload',
    'path': '/home/Drive',
    'create_parents': 'true',
    '_sid': sid,
}

try:
  # Sending the file upload request
  upload_response = requests.post(upload_url, params=upload_params, files=files)
  upload_data = upload_response.json()
except Exception as e:
  print(f'Error uploading file: {e}')
```

When I execute the script it seems to just hang indefinitely when it tries to make the POST request. Am I missing something or what other approaches can I try to upload a file to synology NAS using python?